# Запись числа в файл посредством файловых переменных

Tags: c++

Написал мини функцию, которая записывает определенное число в файл, записывать оно записывает, но в файле в итоге не числа, а иероглифы, либо буквы ,или числа, но не те, что ввел пользователь (например, при вводе числа 12345, программа закинет в файл число 90). Что не так?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Test.txt","wt");
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    fwrite(&i,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В С++ лучше использовать fstream для работы с файлами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пишете в файл бинарное представление числа (те самые иероглифы). Если хотите записать текстовое представление, делайте это, например, так:

```
fprintf(f, "%d", i);
```

Comment: а как тогда можно будет узнать размер открытого файла? Допустим, мне надо контролировать количество введенных чисел (чтобы файл не стал слишком большим), но именно в текстовый файл, а бинарном я бы использовал seekp(), а как поступить с текстовым?

Comment: @IWProgrammer, для определения текущего положения файлового указателя можно использовать ftell(f); Вообще говоря, файловый указатель не всегда бывает в конце, но в данном случае, если вы только пишете, он указывает на конец файла.

Comment: Какой `seekp` при работе с `FILE`? `ftell`

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто путаете текстовый и бинарный формат. То, что пишете вы - бинарный формат; каждое число будет занимать по `sizeof(int)` байт, но записанное в том виде, как хранится в памяти компьютера. Только при этом нельзя использовать текстовый режим, как у вас - `"wt"` - только бинарный.

А если хотите в виде текста - пишите примерно как

```
fprintf("%d",i);
```

Но не лучше ли использовать родные потоки C++? `ofstream`? Зачем эта смесь французского с нижегородским :) - С и С++?

Comment: да, лучше. Но задание стоит через файловые переменные. А для считывания записей тогда какой метод применять?

Comment: Бинарных - `fread`, текстовых - `fscanf`.